# Programatically change relative layout postion with its child views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

How can I change the position of  layout id: rl_generic relative layout programatically?
Currently it is centered. I want its position to change to top left corner for 10 seconds & then top right corner for next 10 seconds with its child views.

```
 <RelativeLayout 
android:id="@+id/ClockScreen"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"       
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:id="@+id/rl_generic"
    android:visibility="visible" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TimeDisplay"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="12:00"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="100sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewDate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TimeDisplay"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingTop="1dp"
        android:text="" />
   </RelativeLayout>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Following code to change the position of your layout.

```
public class SampleActivity extends Activity {

private RelativeLayout miView;
private RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listview);
    miView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_generic);
    params=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d("Sample Acitivity::", "Inside Run MTHD:::");
            miView.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
    }, 5000);
   }
}
```

Let me know your feedbacks..

Comment: Thanks Sivakumar. That worked great. My problem was I was using periodic timertask without a handler & it failed to update the ui.
I also used removeRule to remove previous alignments if any.